# How to dynamically allocate buffer for string while reading file char per char?

Tags: c, string, malloc

How to dynamically allocate buffer for string while reading a file character per character?

I am currently using `malloc` of 1000 (as a limit of strings) but it doesn't seems like a right solution for me.

```
int charIter = 0;

FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!fp)
        error(404);
    else
    {
        buffer = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char*)); //I want this dynamically

        countSntcs = countSentences(fp); // returns number of sntcs in file
        sentences = (char**)malloc(countSntcs * sizeof(char*));

        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            tolower(c);
            if ((c == '\n') || (skip))
            {
                skip = FALSE;
            } 
            else if ((c == '?') || (c == '.') || (c == '!'))
            {
                lenght = countLenght(fp, iterator);
                iterator += lenght;
                sentences[w] = (char*)malloc(lenght * sizeof(char*));
                buffer[charIter++] = c;
                buffer[charIter] = '\0';
                charIter = 0;
                strcpy(sentences[w], buffer);
                w++;
                skip = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                buffer[charIter++] = c;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: "reading fire char per char" - Maybe you better get a fire extinguisher?

Comment: A common workaround to this kind of problem is to start with a rather short array (let's say 10 chars) and each time you reach the limit you use `realloc()` to get a new array 50% larger.

Comment: @jdarthenay Thank you, this solution looks fine!

Comment: @jdarthenay, this is a _king_ of all problems lol :D

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. There are quite some declarations missing. For instance, it is not clear why you use a "pointer to pointer" in the code. Also, don't cast `void *` to other pointers in C.

Comment: It's more efficient, in general, to just malloc 4k pointers and leave it at that if you can.  Unless there is some overriding reason, (ie. a memory-restricted embedded system), why bother with more memory-management  calls if you can avoid them?  If you really insist, you can realloc the buffer down to the 'right size' when no more data will be loaded.